# Sum of Expected Values in $\mathbb{F}_2^N$

Tags: probability, vector-spaces

Given $n,N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n<N$. Let $v\in \mathbb{F}^N_2$ an arbitrary vector result of a certain operation where the expected number of $1$s of $v$ is $n/2$. Let $U\subset{\mathbb{F}^N_2}$ a set of vectors with $m$ 1s. Let $w\in \mathbb{F}^N_2$ a vector uniformly chosen at random from the set $U$. How I could calculate the expected number of $1$s of $v+w$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, I am not sure whether $v$ is to be considered random or not; but it does not impact the answer.

Let
$$V \, \colon= \sum_{i=1}^N v_i, \qquad X \, \colon= \sum_{i=1}^N (v_i + w_i)$$
respectively denote the number of 1s in $v$ and $v+w$.

Since we are doing calculations in $\mathbb{F}_2$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_2$, we have that $a + b = 1$ if and only if $a =1, \, b = 0$ or $a = 0, \, b = 1$. Hence we can write:

$$X = \#\{ i \, \colon \, v_i = 1,\, w_i = 0\} + \#\{ i \, \colon \, v_i = 0,\, w_i = 1\}  $$

We will compute the expectation of $X$ by conditioning on the value of $V$. To simplify formulae we write $p_k \, \colon = \mathbb{P}[V = k]$, then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X] & = \sum_{k = 0}^N p_k \, \mathbb{E}\big[ X\, \big| \, V = k\big]\\
& =\sum_{k = 0}^N p_k \bigg(\mathbb{E}\big[ \#\{ i \, \colon \, v_i = 1,\, w_i = 0\}\, \big| \, V = k\big] + 
\mathbb{E}\big[ \#\{ i \, \colon \, v_i = 0,\, w_i = 1\}\, \big| \, V = k\big] \bigg) 
\end{align*}

Since $w \in U \subset \mathbb{F}_2^N$ is chosen uniformly from those vectors with exactly $m$ 1s, and since (I am assuming, as it was not stated explicitly in the question) $v,w$ are independent we have:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\big[ \#\{ i \, \colon \, v_i = 1,\, w_i = 0\}\, \big| \, V = k\big] & = (N-m) \frac{k}{N}, \\
\mathbb{E}\big[ \#\{ i \, \colon \, v_i = 0,\, w_i = 1\}\, \big| \, V = k\big] & = m \left( 1 - \frac{k}{N} \right).
\end{align*}
An informal derivation of these formulae is to note (in the case of the first) that for each of the $(N-m)$ entries with $w_i = 0$, the probability that the corresponding $v_i = 1$ is $k/N$; the other formula is similar. Of course these can be derived more rigorously.

Given the above, we have:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\big[X\big] & = \sum_{k=0}^N p_k \left( (N-m) \frac{k}{N} + m \left(1 - \frac{k}{N} \right) \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^N p_k m + \sum_{k=0}^N p_k k \left(1-\frac{2m}{N}\right) \\
& = m \sum_{k=0}^N p_k + \left(1-\frac{2m}{N}\right) \sum_{k=0}^N p_k k\\
& = m + \left(1-\frac{2m}{N}\right) \frac{n}{2}
\end{align*}
where to get the final line we noted that $\sum_{k}p_k = 1$, and that $\sum_{k}p_k k = \mathbb{E}[V] = n/2$. So in all we have:

$$ \mathbb{E}\big[X\big] = m + \frac{n}{2} - m \frac{n}{N}$$

In the special case $n = N$, this cancels down to give:
$$ \mathbb{E}\big[X\big] = \frac{n}{2} = \mathbb{E}\big[V\big].$$

**Update: Why can we not use the standard linearity of expectations?**

In a comment by @juaninf, it was suggested that we could use linearity of expectations to say:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N (v_i + w_i) \right]\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N v_i \right] + \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N w_i \right] \\
& = \frac{n}{2} + m
\end{align*}

Whilst this is tempting to believe, we must be very careful. As a simple counter example, consider the case when $m = N$ and $n>0$, so that $U = \{\textbf{1}\} \subset \mathbb{F}_2^N$ is the single point set containing the vector with all entries equal to $1$,$\mathbf{1}_i = 1$. Then, the above formula would say:

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{n}{2} + N > N,$$

which is impossible.

A simple non-probabilistic intuition for why we should not expect this to be true, is to note that in general for $v,w \in \mathbb{F}_2^N$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N(v_i +w_i) \neq \sum_{i=1}^N v_i + \sum_{i=1}^N w_i, $$

which is due to the fact that the $`+`$ sign in the left hand expression denotes addition in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

To understand the issue from a (theoretical) probabilistic perspective, we must first note that random variables are normally defined as being real valued, and not taking values in arbitrary spaces (eg. $\mathbb{F}_2^N$); and hence neither, too, are expectations. Yet, the expectation you ask for (the expected number of $1$s) clearly has `meaning'.

To define this mathematically, we must project the random element of $\mathbb{F}_2^N$ onto $\mathbb{R}$; that is we define $\pi \, \colon \, \mathbb{F}_2^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

\begin{align*}
\pi(x) \,\colon & = \# \{1 \leq i \leq N  \, \colon \, x_i = 1\}.
\end{align*}

Then for any random $u \in \mathbb{F}_2^N$, $\pi(u) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable.

However, the projection operation defined above is not linear: that is to say, given $x,y \in \mathbb{F}_2^N$ it is generally the case that

$$\pi(x + y) \neq \pi(x) + \pi(y),$$

Take for example $x =y = (1,0) \in \mathbb{F}_2^2$ then 
\begin{align*}\pi(x) + \pi(y) = \pi\big( (1,0) \big) + \pi\big( (1,0) \big) &= 2 \\
\pi(x + y) = \pi\big( (1,0) + (1,0) \big) = \pi \big( (0,0) \big) &= 0
\end{align*}

This is really just formalizing the formula previously stated above as
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N(v_i +w_i) \neq \sum_{i=1}^N v_i + \sum_{i=1}^N w_i. $$

From which, combining this with the expectation we have in general

$$\mathbb{E}[ \pi(x + y) ] \neq  \mathbb{E}[\pi(x)] + \mathbb{E}[\pi(y)].$$

So the take home message: using linearity does not fail because of an issue with the probability, but rather because the projection $\pi \colon \mathbb{F}_2^N \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is non-linear.

Comment: thanks by your reply. After publish my question I was looking for a solution and I found this "For any two random variables X and Y, the expected value of the sum of those variables will be equal to the sum of their expected values". According my question the expected value of $v$ is $n/2$ and the expected value of $w$ is always $n$, then the expected value of the sum is $n+n/2$. I am wrong?

Comment: Finally, as a concrete counter example to your formula, consider the case where with probability $1/2$, all entries of $v$ are 0, and probability $1/2$ all entries are $1$. Hence (using my notation above) $$\mathbb{E}[V] = \frac{N}{2},$$ as required in the question. In this case, there is probability $1/2$ that $X = m$ (i.e. when all $v_i = 0$), and probability $1/2$ that $X = N-m$ (when all $v_i =1$). Hence \begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[X] &= \frac12 m + \frac12 (N-m) \\ & = \frac{N}{2} \\ & \neq  m + \frac{N}{2}, \end{align*} contradicting the formula you give based on linearity of expectations.

Comment: You will see above that I have updated my answer to give greater detail about why linearity of expectation fails in this context. Hopefully this resolves your question in the comment, and also the original question you posed.